# SQL Server: ROW_NUMBER() in WHERE clause returns "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, common-table-expression, row-number

Since a few days I'm working with [this](https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone) free and open source database that lists all IP addresses in the World.

My goal is to create a database that could list:

1. All `country_code` in the world
2. All `city_name` in the world taken once
3. `Latitude` and `longitude` of each city
4. A countdown order `desc` on the `country_code`

and I did it:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc,city_name desc) as countdown_order,
AVG(latitude) AS latitude, 
AVG(longitude) AS longitude, 
city_name, 
country_code
FROM ip2location_db11 
--where countdown_order < '100'
GROUP BY country_code, city_name
ORDER BY country_code, city_name
```

[image]

Problems arrives when I uncomment that `where countdown_order < '100'`
The query returns me

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 
Invalid column name 'countdown_order'.
```

[image]

Yes, I tried using `CTE` but it returns me more errors because of the `ORDER BY`.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countdown_order` is a column alias. You can't reference to the column alias at the same level.

However, you can do it at a higher level like a derived table or cte

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc, 
                                      city_name desc) as countdown_order,
          AVG(latitude) AS latitude, 
          AVG(longitude) AS longitude, 
          city_name, 
          country_code   
    FROM  ip2location_db11 
    GROUP BY country_code, city_name
) as D
where countdown_order < 100   -- countdown_order is an integer, remove the single quote
ORDER BY country_code, city_name
```

Comment: One can reference the column alias at the same level in an `ORDER BY` clause but not a `WHERE` clause. This is due to the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql). The `SELECT` clause is logically processed after the `WHERE` clause is evaluated so the column alias is not available at that point.

Comment: I found you Squirrel! Was helpful in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using Common Table Expressions (CTEs). It looks something like this:

```
;WITH MAIN_CTE AS (
SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc, 
                                      city_name desc) as countdown_order,
          AVG(latitude) AS latitude, 
          AVG(longitude) AS longitude, 
          city_name, 
          country_code   
    FROM  ip2location_db11 
    GROUP BY country_code, city_name
) 
SELECT * FROM MAIN_CTE 
WHERE countdown_order < 100
ORDER BY country_code, city_name
```

Comment: Thank you. So it is definitely possible using `CTE`, I just need to bring the `ORDER BY` outside the `CTE`